# Docusaurus Cannot link .md files to one another without removing file extension

Tags: github, markdown, documentation, docusaurus

I am trying to link to another markdown file in Docusaurus
My folder structure is

Docs/Folder/File1.md

Docs/Folder/File2.md

When i link to File2.md, the standard markdown format will be  `[Name](./File2.md)` But Docusaurus will not link it unless i remove the .md file extension.

Video File is
https://youtu.be/6sRDPz9tFLE

Any workaround ?

I simply cannot omit the .md in the end because i want interoperability and be able to use it with my local Markdown editor as well.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From the [docusaurus Markdown links](https://docusaurus.io/docs/markdown-features/links), try without `./`

```
 [Name](File2.md)
```

Both `File2` and `File2.md` should be recognized as legitimated links by Docusaurus.

---

The [OP Rishi](https://stackoverflow.com/users/17325336/rishi) actually confirms in [the comments](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73427612/docusaurus-cannot-link-md-files-to-one-another-without-removing-file-extension/73429097#comment129677463_73429097) this is working:

> Deleted everything, did a clean install of the Docusaurus and now it seems to be functioning as expected.

Comment: I Tried, but as you saw from the video i linked, my docusaurus doesn't recognise it. should i report a bug?  My Config for the project is https://raw.githubusercontent.com/casual-coderr/wiki/main/docusaurus.config.js

Comment: That could be a bug indeed, but double check the file encoding, in case it matters.

Comment: Deleted everything, Did a clean install of the docusaurus and now it seems to be functioning as expected.

Comment: @Rishi Perfect, well done. I have included your comment in the answer for more visibility.